# Python multiprocessing slows down significantly beyond a limit

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, multiprocessing

I'm using this script to generate some test data, and it seems to work well until 1mn records. Beyond that, the script slows down like crazy.

I tried using pool async to distribute the load. The code slows down at high volume in the fake_workers creation (a list of objects in it). Looking to optimize that part to increase performance.

Acc. to tqdm, it becomes 1 iteration/sec at high loads (50 mn). Otherwise, its around 70 iterations/sec for 1 mn.

Can you help figure the bottleneck?

```
import concurrent.futures
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import math
import random
import uuid
from tqdm import tqdm
from datetime import datetime
import time
from faker import Faker
import multiprocessing as mp

fake = Faker()


def generate_data(number_of_records, match_rate = 10):
    now = str(datetime.now()).replace(" ", "_")  # current date and time

    # determine pool size based on number of available CPUs
    pool_size = mp.cpu_count()

    # divide number of records evenly among processes
    num_per_process = int(number_of_records / pool_size)

    # create worker processes
    pool = mp.Pool(pool_size)

    # generate workers in parallel
    results = [pool.apply_async(make_workers, args=(num_per_process, match_rate)) for _ in range(pool_size)]
    workers = [result.get() for result in results]

    # combine results into a single DataFrame
    worker_df = pd.concat([pd.DataFrame(worker) for worker in workers], ignore_index=True)
    worker_df.to_csv(
        f"generated_data_{match_rate}_matchrate_{number_of_records}_records_{now}.csv", index=False)

    print(worker_df.head())

def make_workers(num, match_rate):
    start_time = time.time()
    unique_number = math.floor(num*((100-match_rate)/100))

    first_name_list = generate_first_names(num, match_rate, 300)
    last_name_list = generate_last_names(num, match_rate, 300)
    email_list = generate_emails(num, match_rate, 300)
    phone_list = generate_phones(num, match_rate, 300)
    address_list = generate_street_addresses(num, match_rate, 300)
    city_list = [fake.city() for _ in range(100)]
    state_list = [fake.state() for _ in range(50)]
    postal_list = [fake.postcode() for _ in range(100)]
    rewards_id_list = [x + 6006640000000000 for x in range(unique_number)]
    name_id_list = [x + 740305232 for x in range(unique_number)]
    employee_property_number_list = [x + 1000 for x in range(unique_number)]
    program_id_list = [x + 25 for x in range(unique_number)]
    reward_parent_id_list = [x + 6006640000000000 for x in range(unique_number)]
    phone_type_list = ["HOME", "OFFICE"]

    print(" end of list creation --- %s seconds ---" % (time.time() - start_time))

    start_time = time.time()

    fake_workers = [{
        "loyalty_id": uuid.uuid4().hex,
        "rewards_id": np.random.choice(rewards_id_list),
        "name_id": np.random.choice(name_id_list),
        "first_name": np.random.choice(first_name_list),
        "middle_initial": random.choice('ABCD'),
        "last_name": np.random.choice(last_name_list),
        "program_id": np.random.choice(program_id_list),
        "emp_property_nbr": np.random.choice(employee_property_number_list),
        "reward_parent_id": np.random.choice(reward_parent_id_list),
        "loyalty_program_id": 1,
        "loyalty_program_desc": "BWR",
        "enrollment_dt": fake.date_time_between(start_date='-30y', end_date='now'),
        "zip_code": np.random.choice(postal_list),
        "country": "UNITED STATES",
        "country_code": "US",
        "address1": np.random.choice(address_list),
        "address2": "",
        "address3": "",
        "address4": "",
        "city": np.random.choice(city_list),
        "state_code": fake.state_abbr(False),
        "state_name": np.random.choice(state_list),
        "email_address": np.random.choice(email_list),
        "phone_nbr": np.random.choice(phone_list),
        "phone_type": np.random.choice(phone_type_list)
    } for _ in tqdm(range(num))]

    print(" end of json --- %s seconds ---" % (time.time() - start_time))
    return fake_workers

def generate_first_names(num, match_rate, group_size):
    num_iterations_matching_records = math.ceil((num*(match_rate/100))/group_size)
    num_iterations_unique_records = math.ceil((num*(100-match_rate)/100))
    # lists to randomly assign to workers
    ## unique matching records 
    first_name_list = []
    with tqdm(total=num_iterations_matching_records, desc="Generating unique names") as pbar:
        for x in range(num_iterations_matching_records):
            first_name_list.append(fake.first_name() + str(uuid.uuid4())[:5])
            pbar.update(1)
    ## generate 40% of records 
    matching_first_name_list = []
    with tqdm(total=len(first_name_list)*group_size, desc=f"Generating matching records with match group size {group_size}") as pbar:
        for x in first_name_list:
            for _ in range(group_size):
                matching_first_name_list.append(x)
                pbar.update(1)
    print(f"total matching list-{len(matching_first_name_list)}")
    ## generate remaining unique records
    unique_first_name_list = []
    with tqdm(total=num_iterations_unique_records, desc=f"Generating remaining {num_iterations_unique_records} unique names") as pbar:
        for x in range(num_iterations_unique_records):
            unique_first_name_list.append(fake.first_name() + str(uuid.uuid4())[:5])
            pbar.update(1)
    print(f"total unique list-{len(unique_first_name_list)}")
    final_first_name_list = matching_first_name_list + unique_first_name_list
    print(f"final list-{len(final_first_name_list[:num])}")
    shuffled_final_list = final_first_name_list.copy()
    random.shuffle(shuffled_final_list)
    return shuffled_final_list

def generate_last_names(num, match_rate, group_size):
    num_iterations_matching_records = math.ceil((num*(match_rate/100))/group_size)
    num_iterations_unique_records = math.ceil((num*(100-match_rate)/100))
    # lists to randomly assign to workers
    ## unique matching records 
    last_name_list = []
    with tqdm(total=num_iterations_matching_records, desc="Generating unique names") as pbar:
        for x in range(num_iterations_matching_records):
            last_name_list.append(fake.last_name() + str(uuid.uuid4())[:5])
            pbar.update(1)
    ## generate 40% of records 
    matching_last_name_list = []
    with tqdm(total=len(last_name_list)*group_size, desc=f"Generating matching records with match group size {group_size}") as pbar:
        for x in last_name_list:
            for _ in range(group_size):
                matching_last_name_list.append(x)
                pbar.update(1)
    print(f"total matching list-{len(matching_last_name_list)}")
    ## generate remaining unique records
    unique_last_name_list = []
    with tqdm(total=num_iterations_unique_records, desc=f"Generating remaining {num_iterations_unique_records} unique names") as pbar:
        for x in range(num_iterations_unique_records):
            unique_last_name_list.append(fake.last_name() + str(uuid.uuid4())[:5])
            pbar.update(1)
    print(f"total unique list-{len(unique_last_name_list)}")
    final_last_name_list = matching_last_name_list + unique_last_name_list
    print(f"final list-{len(final_last_name_list[:num])}")
    shuffled_final_list = final_last_name_list.copy()
    random.shuffle(shuffled_final_list)
    return shuffled_final_list

def generate_emails(num, match_rate, group_size):
    num_iterations_matching_records = math.ceil((num*(match_rate/100))/group_size)
    num_iterations_unique_records = math.ceil((num*(100-match_rate)/100))
    # lists to randomly assign to workers
    ## unique matching records 
    email_list = []
    with tqdm(total=num_iterations_matching_records, desc="Generating unique emails") as pbar:
        for x in range(num_iterations_matching_records):
            email_list.append(str(uuid.uuid4())[:3]+ fake.email())
            pbar.update(1)
    ## generate 40% of records 
    matching_email_list = []
    with tqdm(total=len(email_list)*group_size, desc=f"Generating matching records with match group size {group_size}") as pbar:
        for x in email_list:
            for _ in range(group_size):
                matching_email_list.append(x)
                pbar.update(1)
    print(f"total matching list-{len(matching_email_list)}")
    ## generate remaining unique records
    unique_email_list = []
    with tqdm(total=num_iterations_unique_records, desc=f"Generating remaining {num_iterations_unique_records} unique emails") as pbar:
        for x in range(num_iterations_unique_records):
            unique_email_list.append(str(uuid.uuid4())[:3]+fake.email())
            pbar.update(1)
    print(f"total unique list-{len(unique_email_list)}")
    final_email_list = matching_email_list + unique_email_list
    print(f"final list-{len(final_email_list[:num])}")
    shuffled_final_list = final_email_list.copy()
    random.shuffle(shuffled_final_list)
    return shuffled_final_list

def generate_phones(num, match_rate, group_size):
    num_iterations_matching_records = math.ceil((num*(match_rate/100))/group_size)
    num_iterations_unique_records = math.ceil((num*(100-match_rate)/100))
    # lists to randomly assign to workers
    ## unique matching records 
    phone_list = []
    with tqdm(total=num_iterations_matching_records, desc="Generating unique phones") as pbar:
        for x in range(num_iterations_matching_records):
            phone_list.append(fake.phone_number())
            pbar.update(1)
    ## generate 40% of records 
    matching_phone_list = []
    with tqdm(total=len(phone_list)*group_size, desc=f"Generating matching records with match group size {group_size}") as pbar:
        for x in phone_list:
            for _ in range(group_size):
                matching_phone_list.append(x)
                pbar.update(1)
    print(f"total matching list-{len(matching_phone_list)}")
    ## generate remaining unique records
    unique_phone_list = []
    with tqdm(total=num_iterations_unique_records, desc=f"Generating remaining {num_iterations_unique_records} unique phones") as pbar:
        for x in range(num_iterations_unique_records):
            unique_phone_list.append(fake.phone_number())
            pbar.update(1)
    print(f"total unique list-{len(unique_phone_list)}")
    final_phone_list = matching_phone_list + unique_phone_list
    print(f"final list-{len(final_phone_list[:num])}")
    shuffled_final_list = final_phone_list.copy()
    random.shuffle(shuffled_final_list)
    return shuffled_final_list

def generate_street_addresses(num, match_rate, group_size):
    num_iterations_matching_records = math.ceil((num*(match_rate/100))/group_size)
    num_iterations_unique_records = math.ceil((num*(100-match_rate)/100))
    # lists to randomly assign to workers
    ## unique matching records 
    street_address_list = []
    with tqdm(total=num_iterations_matching_records, desc="Generating unique street_addresses") as pbar:
        for x in range(num_iterations_matching_records):
            street_address_list.append(fake.street_address())
            pbar.update(1)
    ## generate 40% of records 
    matching_street_address_list = []
    with tqdm(total=len(street_address_list)*group_size, desc=f"Generating matching records with match group size {group_size}") as pbar:
        for x in street_address_list:
            for _ in range(group_size):
                matching_street_address_list.append(x)
                pbar.update(1)
    print(f"total matching list-{len(matching_street_address_list)}")
    ## generate remaining unique records
    unique_street_address_list = []
    with tqdm(total=num_iterations_unique_records, desc=f"Generating remaining {num_iterations_unique_records} unique street_addresses") as pbar:
        for x in range(num_iterations_unique_records):
            unique_street_address_list.append(fake.street_address())
            pbar.update(1)
    print(f"total unique list-{len(unique_street_address_list)}")
    final_street_address_list = matching_street_address_list + unique_street_address_list
    print(f"final list-{len(final_street_address_list[:num])}")

    shuffled_final_list = final_street_address_list.copy()
    random.shuffle(shuffled_final_list)
    return shuffled_final_list
```

I tried using multiprocessing but it doesn't work at high loads

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside each of your workers, you're doing something which has O(N^2) time complexity. You could be doing it in O(N) time.

Here's a super simplified version of your code:

```py
for size in range(1000, 10001, 1000):
    l = [i for i in range(size)]
    out = []
    begin = time.time()
    for i in range(size):
        out.append(np.random.choice(l))
    end = time.time()
    print(f"size: {size} duration: {end - begin:.2f}")
```

This code makes a list of N elements, then uses `np.random.choice()` to sample that list N times. You'd think that making a list of 10000 elements would be 10 times slower than making a list of 1000 elements, but it's not.

Here's the output of this code:

```
size: 1000 duration: 0.11
size: 2000 duration: 0.43
size: 3000 duration: 0.94
size: 4000 duration: 1.64
size: 5000 duration: 2.54
size: 6000 duration: 3.63
size: 7000 duration: 4.95
size: 8000 duration: 6.41
size: 9000 duration: 8.08
size: 10000 duration: 9.95
```

A 10x increase in size made it 100x slower. Why does this happen? When `np.random.choice()` samples a random element from a list, it first converts the list into a numpy array. This requires copying the entire list.

In contrast, the Python function `random.choice()` can sample from a list without first making a copy of that list.

```
for size in range(1000, 10001, 1000):
    l = [i for i in range(size)]
    out = []
    begin = time.time()
    for i in range(size):
        out.append(random.choice(l))
    end = time.time()
    print(f"size: {size} duration: {end - begin:.2f}")
```

Output of this code:

```
size: 1000 duration: 0.00
size: 2000 duration: 0.00
size: 3000 duration: 0.00
size: 4000 duration: 0.00
size: 5000 duration: 0.00
size: 6000 duration: 0.00
size: 7000 duration: 0.01
size: 8000 duration: 0.01
size: 9000 duration: 0.01
size: 10000 duration: 0.01
```

By replacing `np.random.choice` with `random.choice` everywhere in your code, I find an over 10x speed increase.

**Note**: As an alternative to using `random.choice()`, you could perform the array conversion once, before the loop. Example:

```
    l = np.array(l)
    for i in range(size):
        out.append(np.random.choice(l))
```

This is an alternate way of avoiding the O(N^2) time complexity.

Comment: You've solved this! Thank you so much :) `random.choice` worked like a charm!